# Does each event made from the same delegate type have it's own multicast delegate?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

If I have something like:

```
    static class Program
{
    public static delegate void TestHandler();
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent;
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent1;
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent2;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TestEvent += DoSomething1;
        TestEvent1 += DoSomething2;
        TestEvent2 += DoSomething3;

        Trigger();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Trigger()
    {
        TestEvent();
        TestEvent1();
        TestEvent2();
    }


    private static void DoSomething3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something 3 was done");
    }

    private static void DoSomething2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something 2 was done");
    }

    private static void DoSomething1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something 1 was done");
    }
```

Does each event made form the same type have it's own multicast delegate? How are the invocation lists separated for each event from the same delegate type?

Comment: A delegate type cannot be declared `static`! Your delegate type has the same signature and return type as `System.Action`, so you might use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Delegates` are actually classes. So in your case, there is one type created for `TestHandler` delegate.And there are three different instances of that class.

You can easily see this in generated IL code:

[image]

As you can see there is a `TestHandler` type and there are three fields of that type.So they share the same type but they are completely separate...

Comment: Also in the picture are three `private` fields (near top, shown with "diamonds" with S (for `static`)) which have the same names as the events (bottom of `Program`, "triangles") themselves. Each private field is a reference to an object containing its own invocation list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every `event` has its own multicast delegate backing field. That the event type (and therefore field type) is the same, does not change that.

The code:

```
public delegate void TestHandler();

static class Program
{
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent;
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent1;
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent2;
}
```

more or less means:

```
public delegate void TestHandler();

static class Program
{
    // backing fields with the same names:
    private static TestHandler TestEvent;
    private static TestHandler TestEvent1;
    private static TestHandler TestEvent2;

    // each event is really a pair of two "methods" (accessors)
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent
    {
        add
        {
            // smart code to access the private field in a safe way,
            // combining parameter 'value' into that
        }
        remove
        {
            // smart code to access the private field in a safe way,
            // taking out parameter 'value' from that
        }
    }
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent1
    {
        add
        {
            // smart code to access the private field in a safe way,
            // combining parameter 'value' into that
        }
        remove
        {
            // smart code to access the private field in a safe way,
            // taking out parameter 'value' from that
        }
    }
    public static event TestHandler TestEvent2
    {
        add
        {
            // smart code to access the private field in a safe way,
            // combining parameter 'value' into that
        }
        remove
        {
            // smart code to access the private field in a safe way,
            // taking out parameter 'value' from that
        }
    }
}
```